# How to check the AsyncStorage when user opens the app AND save it to the props

Tags: reactjs, redux, authorization, react-redux, jwt

How do we check the AsyncStorage when user opens the app AND save it to the props.

From this code, I can't save 'token' props

```
  async onAuthComplete(props) {
    let token = await AsyncStorage.getItem("auth_token");
    if(!_.isNull(token)) {
      console.log('token exist! not null!')
      this.props.token = token;
    }
    console.log('props token');
    console.log(this.props.token); <- prints null :(
    if (props.token) {
      this.props.navigation.navigate('Main');
    }
  }
```

I don't want to check AsyncStorage everytime I want to put the token in the header. So I decided it to store it in the props! Is it bad idea? I can't find any examples of authorization flows like Instagram or Facebook.

Let me know if anything is unclear. I'm here to edit the question. :)

->I'm using react-Redux

Thank you so much!

Comment: Are you using redux? They have a rehydrate reducer

Comment: Yes I'm using Redux. I don't know how I can use 'rehydrate reducer' to my application flows. Could you explain more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create action for example: 
`setToken = token => {
  return { type: SET_TOKEN, payload: token } ;
 }` or you can use middlewares such as https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk

then you need to write reducer:

```
export default(state = { token: '' }, action) => {
 switch(action.type) {
  case SET_TOKEN: {
   return { ...state, token: action.payload };
  }
  default: return state;
 }
}
```

then you need to connect redux store to your component(look for 'react-redux')

more details http://redux.js.org/